# The ConnectionString not initialized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Good day All
 i have an issue with connection string
I'm getting this exception

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

on the RowDataBound of the outer gridview sub routine (VB.NET)

when trying to bind data to inner gridview

the code:

```
Private Function ChildDataSource(ByVal strCustometId As String, ByVal strSort As String) As SqlDataSource
    Dim strQRY As String = ""

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()

        strQRY = "SELECT [Sortie].[OdvID],[Sortie].[SortieID]," & "[Sortie].[Fuel],[Sortie].[Captain],[Sortie].[Crew] FROM [Sortie]" & " WHERE [Sortie].[OdvID] = '" & strCustometId & "'" & "UNION ALL " & "SELECT '" & strCustometId & "','','','','' FROM [Sortie] WHERE [Sortie].[OdvID] = '" & strCustometId & "'" & "HAVING COUNT(*)=0 " & strSort

        'Initialize command object
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQRY, conn)
        Dim dsTemp As New SqlDataSource()
        dsTemp.SelectCommand = strQRY
        Return dsTemp
    End Using

End Function
```

This event occurs for each row

```
Protected Sub gvOdv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MoyensAeriensConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()


    Dim row As GridViewRow = e.Row
    Dim strSort As String = String.Empty

    ' Make sure we aren't in header/footer rows
    If row.DataItem Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    'Find Child GridView control
    Dim gv As New GridView()
    gv = DirectCast(row.FindControl("gvSorties"), GridView)

    'Check if any additional conditions (Paging, Sorting, Editing, etc) to be applied on child GridView
    If gv.UniqueID = gvUniqueID Then
        gv.PageIndex = gvNewPageIndex
        gv.EditIndex = gvEditIndex
        'Check if Sorting used
        If gvSortExpr <> String.Empty Then
            GetSortDirection()
            strSort = " ORDER BY " & String.Format("{0} {1}", gvSortExpr, gvSortDir)
        End If

        'Expand the Child grid
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Expand", "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>expandcollapse('div" & DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("OdvID").ToString() & "','one');</script>")
    End If

    'Prepare the query for Child GridView by passing the Odv ID of the parent row

    gv.DataSource = ChildDataSource(DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("OdvID").ToString(), strSort)

    gv.DataBind()

    'Add delete confirmation message for Customer
    Dim l As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("linkDeleteCust"), LinkButton)
    l.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " & "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Customer " & DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "OdvID") & "')")

End Sub
```

thanks (I'v been hunting this error for last 3 hours)

Comment: Well, what's the value of `connString` after it's loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both code snippets use a separate connection string. `ChildDataSource` uses `"SiteConnectionString"` and `gvOdv_RowDataBound` uses `"MoyensAeriensConnectionString"`, hopefully I'm not pointing out the obvious here, but if so, are both of those present in your config file?

Answer (score 0):

When you have created the `SqlDataSource` dynamically in your first code snippet, You haven't set its  `ConnectionString`  property, that's why this error is coming up.

Note that you also haven't assigned any ID to your SqlDataSource. Its better to do this too.
You also need to set the [***ConnectionString***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.connectionstring.aspx) property of [***SqlDataSource***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx).

```
Dim dsTemp As New SqlDataSource()
dsTemp.ID = "mySqlSourceControl"
dsTemp.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStr").ConnectionString
dsTemp.SelectCommand = strQRY
...
```

Rest of things should also be fine like: web.config has a connection string for the key  mentioned [ e.g. `ConnectionStr`  here]

Comment: many thanks Man i just solved the problem using the proper declaration

Comment: Glad to know problem is solved. consider accepting any answer that helped you most

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a SQLDataSource as the gridview's datasource, perhaps return a dataset.

```
    Private Function ChildDataSource(ByVal strCustometId As String, ByVal strSort As String) As DataSet
    Dim strQRY As String = "SELECT [Sortie].[OdvID],[Sortie].[SortieID]," & "[Sortie].[Fuel],[Sortie].[Captain],[Sortie].[Crew] FROM [Sortie]" & " WHERE [Sortie].[OdvID] = '" & strCustometId & "'" & "UNION ALL " & "SELECT '" & strCustometId & "','','','','' FROM [Sortie] WHERE [Sortie].[OdvID] = '" & strCustometId & "'" & "HAVING COUNT(*)=0 " & strSort

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(strQRY, conn)
            Using ds As New DataSet
                If da.Fill(ds) > 0 Then
                    Return ds
                Else
                    Return New DataSet
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

The method to set the datasource of the child gridview remains the same.

Comment: @NetTiger How did this go?